# Why can a function declaration and function definition with same name in the C header file (from redis source)

Tags: c, redis

friends,while exploring the Redis' source code, in the sds.h, I see duplicate declaration( definition) function as below:

```
static inline size_t sdslen(const sds s) {
   struct sdshdr *sh = (void*)(s-(sizeof(struct sdshdr)));
   return sh->len;
}
size_t sdslen(const sds s);
```

Why is there two sdslen without error? And what is the effect of that?

Answer (score 2):

The second line is redundant. A definition is a declaration too. You can declare a function or object multiple times as long as they are not conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

While giving the prototype after (or before) the actual (inline) function definition is redundant and strictly not needed, there are good reason for it still. gcc has a warning

> '-Wmissing-prototypes (C and Objective-C only)'
>        Warn if a global function is defined without a previous prototype
>        declaration.  This warning is issued even if the definition itself
>        provides a prototype.  Use this option to detect global functions
>        that do not have a matching prototype declaration in a header file.
>        ...

so in order to support that, header files should define a prototype for inline functions.